# Accessing Session Variables in JSP passed from Servlet

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets

I have already checked related posts but did not get what I was looking for.

My question is as follows: I have created a web application and using tomcat 8.0.30. There is a login page which forwards username and password to the Login servlet. This servlet, after authentication, sets some session attributes and forwards to loggedin.jsp. When I try to access these attributes in the JSP code, I get null and sees a NULL Pointer Exception. I know that problem sounds similar, but I didn't see any concrete solution for this.

To my surprise, I have observed that if I recompile all servlets and copy their class files in WEB-INF/classes/ before starting tomcat, it works and I don't face any issue in accessing the session attributes in JSP. Why it is so??

I am setting and getting the attributes as:

At Servelet:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
String allroles = null;
// Get Some result. result is not null. I checked!!!!
session.setAttribute("allroles",result);

RequestDispatcher rd  = request.getRequestDispatcher("loggedin.jsp");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

In JSP:

```
String allRoles=null;
allRoles= session.getAttribute("allroles").toString();
```

I did not understand why there is problem at the first place and I really don't know why the problem goes away if I recompile servlets at the beginning. Please help.

Comment: In other words, your problem was caused because your servlet and project wasn't properly recompiled/rebuild/redeployed/restarted? Then why this surprise? Do you realize that your fundamental problem has got nothing to do with "accessing session variables in JSP passed from servlet"? You'd have had exactly the same problem with any other code/task in a servlet class which isn't properly compiled etc afterwards. In case you actually wonder why your servlet wasn't "automatically" compiled etc by whatever tool you're using, then you'd better reframe your question to focus on that instead.

Comment: Well, then why do I need to recompile them every time I start the server? I have written them, compiled them and deployed. Why every time do I need to recompile them. It seems I may be missing something. Can you throw some light onto that.

Comment: Perhaps the tool you're using was (mis)configured to not automatically build and (hot)deploy the project anymore, so that you'd have to do it manually? Hard to tell based on the information provided so far.

Comment: I am not using any tool. I am doing it manually using command line. By the way, what does it mean that servlets are not properly compiled? There were no errors. A class file was created. I put that file at proper place. The system was working fine. Then I rebooted the system. Restarted the server. And the problem appears.

Comment: Then the server is likely (mis)configured to not automatically pickup changes in deploy folder anymore. By default, Tomcat should do it for all files in public webcontent. For all classes and libraries in WEB-INF just a webapp redeploy or server restart should be sufficient, not a whole system reboot.

Comment: You could restart just the webapp itself from the manager app in Tomcat rather than restarting the whole Tomcat service.